# Spring security oauth/token returns 401

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth

I am trying to create a simple app with Spring and Spring Security. 
When I hit the default localhost:8080/oauth/token endpoint with username and password in the body I expect to get a token or an error if a given user does not exist. 
I get 401 though. Why is that?
Here are some of my config files:

```
@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
public static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(PUBLIC_URIS).permitAll();
    }

}

@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Configuration
public static class AuthorizationServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient(CLIENT_ID)
                .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE)
                .scopes(SCOPE);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }
```

Security class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Security extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserService usersService;
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new StandardPasswordEncoder();

@Bean
public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
    return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(usersService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}
```

}

And web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:mvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>pl.kabat.security.configuration.SimpleCORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Could you add the request (for example as cURL command) to your question? What I see is that you didn't configure a client secret in your authentication server. What id and secret did you send in your HTTP `Authentication` header?

Comment: @dur: The request is: POST, localhost:8080/oauth/token { "username":"user", "password":"pass", "grant_type": "password", "client_id": "connect-app" }.

I am afraid I am not sending any Authentication header.

Comment: Did  you solved the question?
Please post the solution and accept your own answser.

Answer (score -1):

From the HTTP specs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401

"The HTTP 401 Unauthorized client error status response code indicates that the request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource."

In other words, what you're getting is **exactly** an authentication error.

Comment: yes, but I get that regardless of what I put in a body. If I put correct username and password I should get a valid token right? Instead I get "Full authentication is required to access this resource" every time

Comment: @furry12: What is the correct password? You didn't configure any password in your authentication server configuration. And by the way, you have to send the client id and client secret, not a username and password.

Comment: @dur: I thought the correct credentials would be the ones for a user I created. (Class user implements UserDetails interface from Spring Framework). I thought it would do the job, but I guess I was wrong.
The request is:

POST, http://localhost:8080/oauth/token/

{
 "username":"user",
 "password":"pass",
 "grant_type": "password",
 "client_id": "connect-app"
}